# Passing array of structures to function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, parameters

Sorry for the noob question I'm just a little confused.
If I have an array of structures in main that I want to pass to a function:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    mayarray[5];
};  
MyStruct StructArray[10]; 

myFunction(StructArray[])
```

Pass to this to a function:

```
void myFunction(struct MyStruct PassedStruct[])
{
    PassedStruct[0].a = 1;
    PassedStruct[0].b = 2;
    // ... etc
}
```

My question is, will calling the function like this modify the data in `StructArray`? I need it to. Would that be call by reference? I'm a little confused. How would I change it so that when I pass the array of structures to the function, the function will modify the array `StructArray`? I'musing visual studio btw.
Thanks.

Comment: No need to apologise, stackoverflow is for questions at all skill levels, particularly when they are as clearly asked as this one is :)

Comment: did anyone in an answer end up mentioning that you can also tack on a '&' after the param type and use c++ call by reference feature explicitly? (I don't do this often because it takes away the added information of a de-reference)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
struct MyStruct PassedStruct[]
```

is *mostly* an alternative syntax for:

```
struct MyStruct * PassedStruct
```

So yes, you will access and modify the original structure.

Just one detail to change, the correct call to to the function is not

```
myFunction(StructArray[]);
```

but:

```
myFunction(StructArray);
```

Now I will try to explain why I used the word ***mostly*** in the above sentence:

I will give some hint at the difference between arrays and pointers, why you shouldn't confuse them (even if I would not say they are unrelated, quite the opposite), and the problem with the above `MyStruct PassedStruct[]` parameter passing syntax.

This is not for beginners, and C++ standard experts should also avoid reading this (because I don't want to get in some - ISO Standard_ war as I enter ISO *undefined behavior* territory - a.k.a. forbidden territory).

Let's begin with arrays:

Imagine a simple structure:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};
```

`MyStruct a1[3];` is the declaration of an array whose items are of the above structure type. The most important thing the compiler does when defining an array is to allocate space for it. In our example it reserved space for 3 structs. This reserved space can be on stack or from global memory resources depending where the declaration statement is.

You can also initialize the struct when declaring it like in:

```
struct MyStruct a1[3] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

Notice that in this example, I didn't initialize the `c` field but just `a` and `b`. This is allowed. I could also use designator syntax if my compiler supports it like in:

```
struct MyStruct a1[3] = {{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}, {a:5, b:6}};
```

Now, there is another syntax for defining an array using empty square backets like in:

```
struct MyStruct a2[] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

The point here is that `a2` is a perfectly normal array just like `a1`. The array size is not implicit, it is given through the initializer: I have three initializers therefore I get an array of three structs.

I could  define an uninitialized array of known size with this syntax. 
For an uninitialized array of size 3 I would have:

```
struct MyStruct a2[] = {{},{},{}};
```

Space is allocated, exactly as with the previous syntax, no pointer involved here.

Let's introduce one pointer:

```
MyStruct * p1;
```

This is a simple pointer to a structure of type MyStruct. I can access fields through usual pointer syntax `p1->a` or `(*p1).a`. There is also an array flavored syntax to do the same as above `p1[0].a`. Still the same as above. You just have to remember that p1[0] is a shorthand for `(*(p1+0))`.

Also remember the rule for pointer arithmetic: adding 1 to a pointer means adding the `sizeof` the pointed object to the underlying memory address (what you get when you use %p printf format parameter). Pointer arithmetic allows access to successive identical structs. That means that you can access structs by index with `p1[0]`, `p1[2]`, etc.

Boundaries are not checked. What is pointed to in memory is the programmer's responsibility. Yes, I know ISO says differently, but that is what all compilers I ever tried do, so if you know of one that does not, please tell me.

To do anything useful with p1, you have to make it point to some struct of type `MyStruct`. If you have an array of such structs available like our `a1`, you can just do `p1=a1` and p1 will point to the beginning of the array. In other words you could also have done `p1=&a1[0]`. It's natural to have a simple syntax available as it's exactly what pointer arithmetic is designed for: accessing arrays of similar objects.

The beauty of that convention is that it allows to completely unify pointer and array access syntax. The difference is only seen by the compiler:

- when it sees `p1[0]`, it knows it has to fetch the content of a variable whose name is `p1` and that it will contain the address of some memory structure.
- when it sees `a1[0]`, it knows `a1` is some constant that should be understood as an address (not something to fetch in memory).

But once the address from `p1` or `a1` is available the treatment is identical.

A common mistake is to write `p1 = &a1`. If you do so the compiler will give you some four letter words. Ok, `&a1` is also a pointer, but what you get when taking the address of `a1` is a pointer to the whole array. That means that if you add 1 to a pointer of this type the actual address will move by steps of 3 structures at once.

The actual type of a pointer of that kind (let's call it `p2`) would be `MyStruct (*p2)[3];`. Now you can write `p2 = &a1`. If you want to access the first struct `MyStruct` at the beginning of the memory block pointed to by `p2` you will have to write somethings like `p2[0][0].a` or `(*p2)[0].a` or `(*(*p2)).a` or `(*p2)->a` or `p2[0]->a`.

Thanks to type system and pointer arithmetic all of these are doing exactly the same thing: fetch the address contained in p2, use that address as an array (a known constant address) as explained above.

Now you can understand why pointers and arrays are *totally different types that should not be confused* as some may say. In plain words pointers are variable that contains an address, arrays are constant addresses. Please don't shoot me C++ Gurus, yes I know that is not the full story and that compilers keep many other informations along with address, size of pointed (addressed ?) object for example.

Now you could wonder why in parameter passing context you can use empty square brackets and it really means *pointer*. ? No idea. Someone probably thought it looked good.

By the way, at least with gcc,  you can also put some value between brackets instead of keeping them empty. It won't make a difference you'll still get a pointer, not an array, and boundaries or type checking are not done. I didn't checked in ISO standard was should be done and if it is required by the standard or if it is a specific behavior.

If you want type checking for boundaries, just use a reference. That may be surprising but this is an area where if you use a reference, the actual type of the parameter is changed from pointer to array (and not from pointer to reference to pointer as may be expected).

```
MyStruct StructArray[10];
```

- header: `void myFunction(struct MyStruct * PassedStruct)`
- caller: `myFunction(StructArray)`
- status: works, you work with a pointer in PassedStruct

- header: `void myFunction(struct MyStruct PassedStruct[])`
- caller: `myFunction(StructArray)`
- status: works, you work with a pointer in PassedStruct

- header: `void myFunction(struct MyStruct (& PassedStruct)[10])`
- caller: `myFunction(StructArray)`
- status: works, you work with a reference to an array of size 10

- header: `void myFunction(struct MyStruct (& PassedStruct)[11])`
- caller: `myFunction(StructArray)`
- status: does not compile, type of array mismatch between prototype and actual parameter

- header: `void myFunction(struct MyStruct PassedStruct[10])`
- caller: `myFunction(StructArray)`
- status: works, PassedStruct is a pointer, size provided is ignored

- header: `void myFunction(struct MyStruct PassedStruct[11])`
- caller: `myFunction(StructArray)`
- status: works, PassedStruct is a pointer, size provided is ignored

Comment: @Philip Potter: yet another C++ zealot ? That's exactly why I put the word *mostly* in my answer. Trying to explain the difference between the two forms is a sure way to loose any C++ beginner (and only a beginner can ask such question). Please, go play with templates and let new people learn C++ ;-)

Comment: downvote gone! the new edit is clearer though, shall we say, verbose? :)

Comment: I'm not C++ begginer and yet don't know the difference between `type argument[]` and `type *argument`; I've been looking for a while in C++ standard and googling around, can any of you point me to a place where I can learn the subtle differences in both notations? @PhilipPotter @kriss

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus: in the context of parameter passing there is no difference. This is just two syntaxes for the same thing. Actually even if you put a size between the suqare brackets C++ will still understand the parameter as a pointer (and never copy arrays as people would expect for pass-by-value and the way it is done with say structures).

Comment: If we put the size within the brackets, the type of the parameter will be `int[size]` not `int *` but the `int[size]` will decay to `int *` (`f(int*)` and `f(int[size])` would be ambiguous). The array-to-pointer decay is well documented in C++ standard but I'm unable to find where the `type[]` semantics are documented. Do you know?

Comment: @paula-plus-plus: no, check the documentation/. even if we put the size inside the brackets (in function parameters, elsewhere it's not the same) the parameter is still a pointer. The C++ compiler just ignore the size. Just try it on a compiler, you'll see.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    
    int fn(char x[1000]){
           printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
    }

    int main()
   {
        char t[30] = {};
        fn(t);
    }

Comment: @paula-plus-plus: the way c++ handle the parameter declaration is not a decay. Decay is about the actual instance of pointers or arrays (cases where arrays are converted to pointers behind the scene), but this is not what happens here. Taking the sizeof of the parameter should make it obvious in my exemple.

Comment: Thanks for the information @kriss I'm very interested in knowing where in the C++ standard all the `type[]` oddness is explained, I was unable to find out (maybe isn't stated on the standard?). Do you know where this is explained? (thanks)

Comment: The relevant line comes from function declaration details, there is a line stating: ```If the type is "array of T" or "array of unknown bound of T", it is replaced by the type Pointer to T``` (quoted from cppreference, not comiteed draft).

Comment: @paula_plus_plus: the relevant quote from draft is here: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5

Answer (score 9):

Although arrays and pointers are conceptually different things, the waters are very much muddied by function parameters. You can't directly pass an array to a function; you can only pass a pointer. As a result, the language "helpfully" converts a prototype such as this:

```
void foo (char arr[])
```

into this:

```
void foo (char *arr)
```

And when you call the function, you don't pass it a complete array, you pass a pointer to the first element. As a result, inside the function `foo`, it will have a pointer to the *original* array, and assigning to elements of `arr` will change the array in the caller as well.

In *all* other situations outside of function parameters, array and pointer syntax in declarations are *not* equivalent, and refer to conceptually different things. But inside function parameter lists, array syntax creates pointer types.

Comment: I generally pass the pointer explicitly so it's clear what I had intended. It's just personal preference though

Comment: I tried to explain without any previous knowledge necessary (and mostly with a C point of view) the difference between pointers and array. It was fun to write, but I believe the result is gory.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a std::vector instead. Arrays are very much C constructs, C++ has wrapper classes to prevent exactly these kind of ambiguities

Comment: you still have to use pointers to get a reference, and passing by value when copy constructors are present brings silent overhead if you don't realize it's happening

Answer (score 1):

I believe the x[] means the same thing as x* which means "pointer to the type".  Since this is the case, you will be modifying the object you pass (you'll need to call it using the &, or 'address of' operator), and you can think of it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array as an argument to a function, the array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.

So, when inside your function you use [] to access the elements of the array, you are really only doing pointer arithmetics with your initial pointer to get the elements of the ORIGINAL array.

So, yeah, you are modifying the original array. And this answer is pretty much independent of what compiler you are using (Although it's good practice, IMHO, to state the compiler in the question like you did)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, calling it by reference or by simple ways it will change the original data of the structure array. As we have also solve it on Visual Studio and the answer is in favour. Coode is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct mystr {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    int myarray[2];
};
void insert(mystr Passed[]) {
    Passed[0].a = 5;
    Passed[0].b = 6;
}

void modify(mystr PassedStruct[]) {
    PassedStruct[0].a = 1;
    PassedStruct[0].b = 2;
   
}
int main() {
    mystr StructArray[2];

    insert(StructArray);
    modify(StructArray);

    // Now StructArray has been modified by myFunction
  
    cout << StructArray[0].a << " " << StructArray[0].b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the code first we given the array simple values then using modify function we modify it and after printing original answer was modified.

Comment: What is the added value of your answer compared to the others? Naming your function `insert` is somewhat misleading, as you are not inserting any value. The array has a fixed length.