# why different answers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Below are 2 programs

**First**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *p;
    p=&a;
    printf("%u %u",p,p+1);
}
```

**Second**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%u %u",&a,&a+1);
}
```

Now, in the two programs..I have printed the values of &a using p in first code and directly in the second..

Why are the results different?

the answer i m getting are.

```
for first  3219048884  3219048888
for second 3219048884  3219048904
```

Comment: Could you please format your lines of code with the code button in the editor? Makes it a lot easier for people to help out.

Comment: What are the results you're getting?

Comment: And what are the results that you see?

Comment: Others have pointed out problems here.  I will add: printing a pointer with `%u` is bad news.  Use `%p`.  Moreover, printing a pointer for any reason other than debugging purposes doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Don't use `void main()`; use `int main()` or `int main(void)` or ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The type of `&a` is `int (*) [5]`.  Therefore `&a+1` is a pointer that's 5 `int`s further on than `a`.  However the type of `p` is `int *`, therefore `p+1` is a pointer that's 1 `int` further on than `p`.

Comment: Yes, but that's irrelevant with the question except for the last value of the serie

Comment: @kriss: How is this irrelevant?  It's the last value in each sequence that differ, and this is why.

Comment: with your compiler may be, with mine every set of value is different at each run. The C standard does not guarantee the stability of stack addresses. As the OP exhibited two programs the two outputs can potentially be totally different at each run (they are on my system). Your answer is fine if we combine both programs in one.

Comment: @kriss: Oh I see.  That's a fair point.  However, given the OP's example output, I think it's clear he's referring to the differing last values only.

Answer (score 7):

When I run that, I get this:

```
1245036 1245040 1245036 1245040
1245036 1245040 1245036 1245056
```

with the only difference being in the last position, `p+1` vs `&a+1`

`p` is a pointer to an integer, so `p+1` is the address of the next integer. (i.e 4 byte further in memeory)

`a` is an array of 5 integers, so &a+1 is the address of the next array of 5 integers. (i.e., 20 bytes further in memeory)

Answer (score 2):

In both programs, you are printing the memory addresses of the array.

This can vary each time you run the program.  The memory that the OS chooses to give you can be different.

When your program declares an array of 5 integers, The OS promises to give you 5 consecutive integers, it does NOT promise what memory you will get, or that you will get the same memory every time.

Answer (score 2):

You have two programs with different stack frames, no surprise the addresses of local variables are different. Il may change each time you run the program (that's what it does when I try it, code compiled with gcc on Linux).

But you'll get the same values with the program below one except for the last value of the serie (except for the last one, because of the way pointer arithmetic works).

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()  
{ 
    int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};  
    int *p; 
    p=&a; 
    printf("%u %u %u %u ",a,a+1,p,p+1);
    printf("%u %u %u %u",a,a+1,&a,&a+1);
}
```

For a (quite) complete explanation of difference between pointers and arrays you can look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613302/passing-array-of-structures-to-function-c/3613350#3613350)

Answer (score 1):

Your first program is invalid. It is illegal to assign `p = &a`, since `p` has type `int *` and `&a` has type `int (*)[5]`. These types are not compatible. If your compiler is loose enough to allow this kind of assignment (did it at least warn you?), it probably interpreted it as `p = (int *) &a`, i.e. it forcefully reinterprets the value of `&a` as an `int *` pointer. Thus, all pointer arithmetic in your first program is `int *` arithmetic. This is why the first program produces the same output for `a+1` and `p+1` values.

In the second program the value of `&a` is not reinterpreted. It keeps its original type ``int (*)[5]`and it follows the rules of normal pointer arithmetic for type`int (*)[5]`, meaning that when you do`&a + 1`, the pointer is moved`sizeof(int[5])` bytes, as it should. This is why the result is different from the first program.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `p = a` and not `p = &a`. An array like `a` is already assumed a constant pointer. You do not need to dereference it with the `&` operator.

Comment: @GMan Why then can you say `*a = 2` with the same meaning as `a[0] = 2`?

Comment: Because arrays have an implicit conversion to pointer. But arrays are not pointers.