# How to pass array of structures to function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to pass array of structures to a function and I make it this way:
it's my function

```
void ShowRoutes(Route *routeList, int n, string title) { //... }
```

and it's function call

```
ShowRoutes(routeList, n, "Unsorted list: ");
```

but I would like to know are there other ways to pass array of structures to function?

Comment: I'd recommend `std::array` or `std::vector`, depending on when you know the size.

Comment: I have just started learning C++, I don't know `std::array` or `std::vector` yet.

Comment: They're typically easier to deal with than plain arrays (and especially dynamic arrays). They're a worthy investment.

Comment: If you just started, you may as well learn some good practices now. It's worth the time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array of structures to function c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613302/passing-array-of-structures-to-function-c)

Comment: Instead of passing data around, encapsulate it and perform operations on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I know of to pass arrays to functions.

The way you have it:

```
void ShowRoutes(Route *routeList, int n, string title) { //... }
```

or

```
void ShowRoutes(Route routeList[], int n, string title) { //... }
```

Either way you write the function, you would still call it the same way:

```
ShowRoutes(routeList, n, "Unsorted list: ");
```

But as others mentioned, would be a good idea to learn std::array and std::vector.