# Passing array of different structures to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, parameter-passing

I need to pass different array of structures to function, but I don't know how to do it. Each time, I'm getting an error. I go through the Internet but all examples I found are about passing specific or only one array of structure to function ([Passing array of structures to function c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613302/passing-array-of-structures-to-function-c)) but what if I have different structures each time and I want to pass it to the same function.

So I'm not sure if what I want to do is applicable or not.

To clarify more if I have the following structures:

```
struct EVRL_Mapping2 {
    double avgMap2;
    int permutationMap2[2];
};
struct EVRL_Mapping3 {
    double avgMap3;
    int permutationMap3[3];
};
struct EVRL_Mapping4 {
    double avgMap4;
    int permutationMap4[4];
};
EVRL_Mapping2 EVRL_Map2[2]; //Mapping2: AC3,AC2 (2 mapping)
EVRL_Mapping3 EVRL_Map3[2]; //Mapping3: AC3,AC2,AC1 (2 mapping)
EVRL_Mapping4 EVRL_Map4[1]; //Mapping4: AC3,AC2,AC1,AC0 (1 mapping)
```

Now in the .CC code, if I have an array of two elements of EVRL_Mapping2 (EVRL_Map2[2]) and I want to find the maximum of avgMap2 between the two elements of structure and return the index/location of that element. Is it going to be like this: 
if yes, does it mean for each structure I need to define a separate function!?

```
int findMax(struct EVRL_Mapping2 myarray[], int size){
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
//  printf("myarray[%d]=%d\n",i,myarray[i]);
}
    double max = myarray[0].avgMap2;       
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<size; i++)
    {
    if(myarray[i] > max){
        max = myarray[i].avgMap2;
        index = i;
        printf("Inside if(): index=%d\n",index);
    }
    }
    return index; 
printf("Inside findMax(): index=%d\n",index);
}
```

Now calling and passing to this function:

```
findMax(EVRL_Map2,2);
```

However, I have an error with the above function definition and the code doesn't compile.So can you advise?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to have the compilation error(s).

Comment: One option in C99 and later is to use a _flexible array member_: `struct EVRL_MappingN { double aveMap; int perm_size; int permutationMap[]; };`.  This is probably what I'd use.  Alternatively, use a pointer to the array: `struct EVRL_MappingP { double aveMap; int perm_size; int *permutationMap; };` and use `malloc()` or equivalent to allocate the correct size of permutation map.

Comment: @mattm : The error `apps/udp.cc:333: error: no matching function for call to ‘UdpAgent::findMax(UdpAgent::EVRL_Map2 [2], int)’
apps/udp.h:62: note: candidates are: virtual int UdpAgent::findMax(EVRL_Map2*, int)
apps/udp.cc: At global scope:
apps/udp.cc:599: error: prototype for ‘int UdpAgent::findMax(UdpAgent::EVRL_Map2*, int)’ does not match any in class ‘UdpAgent’
apps/udp.h:62: error: candidate is: virtual int UdpAgent::findMax(EVRL_Map2*, int)`